# Not quite understanding the query after just shifting column names

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, self-join

This is my table **tblEmployee** ,when I'm trying to use a self join query it's result is varying while shifting columns, can someone please explain me the difference between those two queries.Thanks

```
EmployeeID  Name    ManagerID
 1          Mike     3
 2          Rob      1
 3          Todd    NULL
 5          Ben      1
 6          Sam      1
```

> Query_1

```
SELECT E.Name AS Employee, M.Name AS Manager
from tblEmployee E
LEFT JOIN tblEmployee M
on E.ManagerID = M.EmployeeID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Employee    Manager
 Mike        Todd
 Rob         Mike
 Todd        NULL
 Ben         Mike
 Sam         Mike
```

> QUERY_2

```
SELECT E.Name AS Employee, M.Name AS Manager
from tblEmployee E
LEFT JOIN tblEmployee M
on E.EmployeeID = M.ManagerID
```

**OUTPUT**

```
Employee  Manager
Mike       Rob
Mike       Ben
Mike       Sam
Rob        NULL
Todd       Mike
Ben        NULL
Sam        NULL
```

Comment: It's going the "other" way...

Comment: Can you tell us, what kind of result you need?

Comment: Not bothered about result, just wanted to know the differences between the 'ON' condition of both of those queries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First a simple explanation: the left join takes every row in the first table that has at least a match in the second table on the column you selected.

In the **first query** you are considering the *Manager ID* on every row and looking for a match on the *Employee ID* in the second table: since value in the second table (*Employee ID*) is a ***key*** (at least in the example definition), you can find only one row that matches that ID.

Eg: First row Mike has *Manager ID* = 3, when you are looking at the table you have only one row that has *Employee ID* = 3, and that is Todd

In the **second query** you are considering the *Employee ID* on every row and looking for a match on the *Manager ID* in the second table: since there could be more than one row with the same *Manager ID*, you will receive more value for every row.

Eg: First row Mike has *Employee ID* = 1, when you are looking at the table you have three rows with *anager ID* = 1 and those are Rob, Ben and Sam.

Comment: It's clear now, basically in Query_1 we take up the ManagerID and lookup in the Emp_ID....Thanks

Comment: Exactly! And viceversa in Query_2

Answer (score 1):

With **Query1** you are selecting each employee (E) and their manager (M) if there is one (left join).

With **Query2** you reversed that. You are selecting each employee (E) and their subordinates (M). The alias for `M.Name` is incorrect now, because it's not the manager but a subordinate. As some employees have more than one subordinate, they are listed once for each of them (Mike).

Answer (score 1):

Basically the second query is little out of order in the sense that since you have swapped the join criteria columns, you get

> all combination of manager name followed by the employee name they are manager of

unlike the first query which gave you

> all combination of employee names followed by their manager name

So your corrected 2 query should be

```
SELECT E.Name AS Manager, M.Name AS Employee -- note changes here
from tblEmployee E
LEFT JOIN tblEmployee M
on E.EmployeeID = M.ManagerID
```

**OUTPUT**

**`Manager`**  **`Employee`**

```
Mike       Rob
Mike       Ben
Mike       Sam
Rob        NULL
Todd       Mike
Ben        NULL
Sam        NULL
```

Or maybe you wanted the same result the other way round

then your query should be using `RIGHT JOIN` instead of `LEFT JOIN`

```
SELECT E.Name AS Employee, M.Name AS Manager
from tblEmployee E
RIGHT JOIN tblEmployee M -- note the change in JOIN
on E.EmployeeID = M.ManagerID
```

**OUTPUT**

**`Employee`  `Manager`**

```
 Todd        Mike   
 Mike        Rob    
 NULL        Todd   
 Mike        Ben    
 Mike        Sam
```

Comment: Now I think it solved my doubt. appreciate your effort, thanks